# Is COMMIT required after ending a transaction in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have a stored procedure that reads rows from a table, do some calculations for each row and stores the result in the same row.

When I need to process a million rows, **all the UPDATES are filling up the DBC database**, so I want to do a COMMIT after 1000 row calculations.

Do I need to use transactions o do I need to use COMMIT?
What does COMMIT WORK do?

I execute all in TERA mode and the version is 15.00.

This an example simplified of my procedure:

```
-- Creates a sample table
--DROP TABLE DM_CALIDAD.RGR_TEST_PROCEDURE;
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DM_CALIDAD.RGR_TEST_PROCEDURE AS(
SELECT T.TABLENAME AS "TABLE_NAME", 0(INTEGER) AS IND_NAME FROM DBC.TABLESV T
)WITH DATA
;

--Creates the procedure
REPLACE PROCEDURE DM_CALIDAD.SP_TEST_NAME()
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE V_CALC INTEGER;
    DECLARE SQL_CURSOR1, SQL_UPDATE VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE CONT INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE CUR_CURSOR1 CURSOR FOR PREP_CURSOR1;

    SET SQL_CURSOR1 = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DM_CALIDAD.RGR_TEST_PROCEDURE';

    SET CONT = 1;
    PREPARE PREP_CURSOR1 FROM SQL_CURSOR1;
    OPEN CUR_CURSOR1;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    l_loop: 
    LOOP

        FETCH CUR_CURSOR1 INTO V_TABLE_NAME;

        IF (SQLCODE <> 0) THEN
            LEAVE l_loop;
        END IF;

        SET SQL_UPDATE = 'UPDATE DM_CALIDAD.RGR_TEST_PROCEDURE SET IND_NAME = IND_NAME+1 WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''' ||V_TABLE_NAME || '''';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_UPDATE;

        -- Ends the transacion each 1000 updates 
        SET CONT = CONT + 1;
        IF (CONT MOD 1000 = 0) THEN
            END TRANSACTION;
            --COMMIT WORK;
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        END IF;

    END LOOP l_loop;
    END TRANSACTION;
    CLOSE CUR_CURSOR1;

END;

-- Calls procedure
CALL DM_CALIDAD.SP_TEST_NAME();
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit1, more details.

What I'm really trying to calculate is how many labour days are between two dates considering bank holidays (or festives day) and weekends for each city.

For example, I'm sending something from A to B, and I have a tracking event that says it was at A on Friday, Feb 1st, and at B the next Wednesday, Feb 6th, so for B I need to query all the days in between those dates looking for festive days.

For this propose, I have a table with 2 columns, city and festive day.

```
CITY | FESTIVE
  B    2019-02-02 -- For being Saturday
  B    2019-02-03 -- For being Sunday
  B    2019-02-04 -- For being festive at B
```

So for each row I read the column *first_event* and the column *last_event* and do the difference (6-1 = 5days) and then I calculate the days off for B
`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FESTIVES_TABLE WHERE CITY='B' AND FESTIVE BETWEEN DATE '2019-02-01' AND DATE '2019-02-06')` and it returns 3 days, which then I subtract them to the 5days (day 06 - day 01 = 5days, 5days-3festives = 2days).

So the amount of labour days is 2, and then I update the row with the value calculated.

I have checked the perm space for DBC database and it has 1962GBytes.

Thanks again :)

Comment: I try to avoid stored procs when I can, so maybe I'm missing something, but what is the value of using  cursor here?

Comment: COMMIT must be used in ANSI mode sessions, in Teradata mode it's BEGIN/END transaction. You want to process a million rows using a cursor? Ouch. There's almost no reason to process data sequentially and in a parallel DBMS like Teradata it's worst case. I can hardly believe that processing a few million rows can fill DBC, can you add more details what you're actually doing?

Comment: Andrew, it was just an example for the BEGIN/END transaction.
@dnoeth, I've udpated the question with more details about what I'm really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple way to calculate the number of business (or holidays) days without loops/counts/etc, it's based on a calculated business_day number column in a calendar table. In your case it's slightly more complicated because you need multiple calendars, one per city.

So let's calculate it in a View (or use a Common Table Expression, `WITH my_cal AS SELECT ...`):

```
REPLACE VIEW my_cal AS
SELECT c.*,
  -- running business day number
  -- increases only for each business day
  Sum(CASE WHEN f.festive IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)
  Over (PARTITION BY c.city
        ORDER BY c.caldt
        ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS business_day_num
FROM 
 ( -- this simply create all dates for each city
   SELECT *
   FROM 
    ( -- all cities
      SELECT DISTINCT city
      FROM festivetable
    ) AS f
   CROSS JOIN 
    ( -- all dates
      SELECT calendar_date AS caldt
      FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR AS c -- you should use your company's calendar instead
      WHERE caldt BETWEEN DATE '2018-10-01' AND DATE '2019-02-28' 
    ) AS c
 ) AS c
LEFT JOIN festivetable AS f
  ON  c.city = f.city
 AND c.caldt = f.festive;
```

Now it's just two joins on start_date/end_date and calculate the difference.

```
SELECT ...
   end_cal.business_day_num - start_cal.business_day_num AS duration_in_business_days
FROM mytable
JOIN my_cal AS start_cal
  ON mytable.city = start_cal.city
 AND mytyble.first_event = start_cal.caldt
JOIN my_cal AS end_cal
  ON mytable.city = end_cal.city
 AND mytyble.first_event = end_cal.caldt
```

Regarding DBC, when you say *all the UPDATES are filling up the DBC database* do you mean the Transient Journal? Well, this can grow much larger than dbc (if there's space available on your system).

But 2TB Perm Space is quite low for dbc (unless you got a very small system), how big is your target table and which percentage of rows is updated?

Comment: I've created a new table with the work days for all the cities (30.000) for 3 moving years and I'm using scalar subquerys to calculate the values I need for each delivery. Thank you for the idea :) About the system, we have 72 AMPs and 11TB perm space in total. How big can an average teradata system be?

Comment: Be careful with Scalar Subqueries, the plan might be worse than joins, check Explain. 2 TB out of 11 is fine. I don't know about the average system, but the big ones are PBs